# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: database is locked

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (dataGridFNum.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                //Insert to database
                sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=LotteryCheck.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_select;
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_select2;
                sqlite_conn.Open();
    
                sqlite_cmd_select = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
    
                sqlite_cmd_select.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LotteryList Order by SectionId desc";
    
                sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd_select.ExecuteReader();
                int id = 1;
                while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
                {
                    id = sqlite_datareader.GetInt32(0) + 1;
    
                    break;
                }
                SectionS.Add(id);
                lblNum.Text = SectionS.Count.ToString();
    
                sqlite_cmd_select2 = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd_select2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LotteryList Order by Ref_id desc";
    
    
                sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd_select2.ExecuteReader();
                int refId = 1;
                while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
                {
                    refId = sqlite_datareader.GetInt32(5) + 1;
                    break;
                }
    
                sqlite_datareader.Dispose();
    
    
                sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                for (int count = 0; count < dataGridFNum.Rows.Count; count++)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into LotteryList ( SectionId ,Datet , LotNo , SubNo , NumNo , Ref_id) VALUES ('" + id + "' ,'" + (String)dataGridFNum.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value + "' " +
                        ", '" + (String)dataGridFNum.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value + "' , '" + (String)dataGridFNum.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value + "' , '" + (String)dataGridFNum.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value + "','" + refId++ + "' )";
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           
                }
                sqlite_conn.Close();
      }
}
```

***This is my example code and Its error at the line "sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();***

***This code always work in the first time when I click Done button but when I click it again ,It will face the error below.***

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
> HResult=0x800007AF
> Message=database is locked
> database is locked
> Source=System.Data.SQLite
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at LotteryHappy.Check.btnDone_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

***I also use Close() for all connection in my code but still not work.***

Comment: you need to do 'using' on all those objects,: connection, reader, command, you are not disposing of everthing. you did not dispose the first reader - thats the specifc error here

Comment: see eample here for using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli